# Cut the variable of a datatable passed to a user defined function as parameters

Tags: r, function, data.table, cut

I have a user defined function in 'helpers.R' called 'percent_map' which accepts the parameters as follows:

```
percent_map <- function(DT,var,statelist, pal,legend.title)
```

where

- DT is a datatable,
- var is a variable present in datatable that needs to be cut in 5 equal parts
- pal is for getting a palette name and statelist is a list US states

The result/coded value is stored back in the DT as a new variable called percents.

I have currently programmed the function as below:

```
    percent_map <- function(DT,var,statelist, pal, legend.title) {

      # generate vector of fill colors for map
      shades <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(5, pal)

      # constrain gradient to percents that occur between variable range
      ##********Error in the below statement*************
      DT[,percents:=as.integer(cut(DT[,var], 5, include.lowest = TRUE))]



      names <- DT[match(map("state", plot=FALSE)$names,as.character(tolower(DT[,statelist]))),statelist]
      colorsmatched<-DT[match(names,as.character(DT[,statelist])),percents]
      fills <- shades[colorsmatched]  

#map plotting function here 
    }
```

**I am getting the following error on passing my datatable visabystate**

```
 percent_map(DT=visabystate,var = 'casesbystate',statelist='employer_state', pal = "Greens",legend.title="No. of cases")
 Hide Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in cut.default(DT[, var], 5, include.lowest = TRUE) : 
  'x' must be numeric 
8 stop("'x' must be numeric") 
7 cut.default(DT[, var], 5, include.lowest = TRUE) 
6 cut(DT[, var], 5, include.lowest = TRUE) 
5 eval(expr, envir, enclos) 
4 eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame()) 
3 `[.data.table`(DT, , `:=`(percents, as.integer(cut(DT[, var], 
    5, include.lowest = TRUE)))) at helpers.R#11
2 DT[, `:=`(percents, as.integer(cut(DT[, var], 5, include.lowest = TRUE)))] at helpers.R#11
1 percent_map(DT = visabystate, var = "casesbystate", statelist = "employer_state", 
    pal = "Greens", legend.title = "No. of cases")
```

*How to solve this such that the end result is the same?* Here is the str(visabystate)

```
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  50 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ employer_state : Factor w/ 50 levels "Alabama","Alaska",..: 23 36 43 46 5 10 30 33 22 6 ...
 $ casesbystate   : int  2359 603 58586 13080 62708 11107 57028 15313 14347 2247 ...
 $ fulltimebystate: int  4657 1184 116310 25319 122853 22005 113501 30554 28568 4429 ...
 $ workersbystate : int  3113 645 120640 21117 125647 14395 119051 15634 35751 2659 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Things I have tried:

The expression works interactively if i use

```
visabystate[,percents:=as.integer(cut(visabystate[,casesbystate], 5, include.lowest = TRUE))]
```

However, it does not work if DT$var is used inside cut within the percent_map function. It gives the same error.

**EDIT**

Added with=FALSE in the cut statement as below

```
DT[,percents:=as.integer(cut(DT[,var,with=FALSE], 5, include.lowest = TRUE))]
```

It gives the additional messages as below:

```
The following objects are masked from DT (pos = 3):

    casesbystate, employer_state, fulltimebystate, workersbystate

The following objects are masked from DT (pos = 4):

    casesbystate, employer_state, fulltimebystate, workersbystate

The following objects are masked from DT (pos = 5):

    casesbystate, employer_state, fulltimebystate, workersbystate

 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in cut.default(DT[, var, with = FALSE], 5, include.lowest = TRUE) : 
  'x' must be numeric
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the problem comes from `var = 'casesbystate'`. It should be `var = casesbystate` (without quotes). See the difference between `visabystate[, 'casesbystate']` and `visabystate[, casesbystate]`. Alternatively, you can use the `with=FALSE` argument if you want to pass a string while subsetting a `data.table`.

Comment: Yes, I think so too. However, I need to pass the variable name as a parameter and passing it as a string seems to be the only way. with=FALSE is not working as well unfortunately. I have updated the question to show the error

Comment: You should start a fresh session. However, if you need a single column, the standard `DT[[var]]` should work.

Comment: Just use `DT[[var]]` not `DT[,var]`. This is covered early on on the data.table FAQs: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: You need to check whether the variable `x` is a factor or a character or a numeric. For the `cut`, it should be numeric.

Comment: Thanks @nicola & @Frank! That worked. Really silly mistake on my side!

Comment: @user227710- It's an integer. I was trying to extract column wrongly.